# Log processing - send each new line in a log file as a parameter to script in real time

Tags: shell, logging, rsyslog

I have an active log file (which means there are new lines of log information appended to the file in real time).

What I want: When there is a new line appended, pass the new line of log as a parameter to a script (Bash, C, or even PHP).

What is better: instead of open a new process for every new line of log appended, run a demon process in the background to accept each line of new input.

I tried to Google, but haven't found any useful keyword to start.

By the way, it's running on Debian.

Comment: It sounds like you want a variant of `tail  -f` that executes a script with each line as it is appended to the log file.  I think you'll have to write that, probably.  It shouldn't be too hard to do, but most people have not found it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> instead of open a new process for every new line of log appended, run
>   a demon process in the background to accept each line of new input.

```
tail -f log | demon&
```